# Apache Spark degraded performance in local mode

Tags: apache-spark, local, scalability, mode

I am running a simple performance test for Spark 2.0.2 [from here](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html) I use Pi Estimation example on a laptop with 4 cores and 16GB of memory like this:

```
$ ./bin/spark-shell --master=local[1] --name=shell_1

scala> val NUM_SAMPLES=160000000
NUM_SAMPLES: Int = 160000000
```

Then I copy/paste code for Pi calculation.

```
val count = sc.parallelize(1 to NUM_SAMPLES).map{i =>
  val x = Math.random()
  val y = Math.random()
  if (x*x + y*y < 1) 1 else 0
}.reduce(_ + _)
println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / NUM_SAMPLES)
```

Here are my results:

```
$ ./bin/spark-shell --master=local[1] --name=shell_1
12 sec

$ ./bin/spark-shell --master=local[2] --name=shell_2
22 sec

$ ./bin/spark-shell --master=local[4] --name=shell_4
40 sec

$ ./bin/spark-shell --master=local[8] --name=shell_8
45 sec
```

I don't see how Spark is scaling with the number of cores and clearly there is clear performance degradation with the increase of number of executor cores. I understand this may not be a valid test, since the configuration is not truly distributed, yet I'd be very interested to hear explanation for this behavior.

Comment: this could happen due to excessive parallelization. Try to process around 5GB data, you might see the diff with more cores.

Comment: Excessive parallelization of 4 local executors on 600MB dataset? I don't see how this is happening. Nevertheless I run the test on 6GB data and all numbers are roughly x10 more. Same degradation with increase of number of parallel processes. If Spark can't effectively scale parallel operations on the same machine, where operations happen in memory, how can it do this efficiently on a cluster of machines connected over much slower network?

Comment: out of 4 cores in local machine (1 driver, 1 application master and 2 for executors). Here we are not doing full parallelization after 2 cores and making threads to wait for execution. so **time will be taken for context switching than executing the task**. I'd recommend benchmarking in a cluster which has some good number of cores(overall).

Answer (score 2):

What does the explain plan look like? Have you tried profiling it? I suspect you are hitting I/O bottlenecks. Spark likes to shuffle to disk, and there are no in memory shuffle optimizations for local mode. This hurts users that want to scale vertically on single nodes with monster hardware. Make sure you configure shuffle partitions to a low number. The defaults are nonsense for smaller scales of data. Make sure your local / scratch dir is mounted to SSD or RAM based volume, if you can afford the memory.